# Mapping to destination when actual destination type is a dynamic proxy generated by entity framework

Tags: ef-code-first, automapper

I can't get this to work:

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>();

var context = new MyDbContext();

var source = new Source();
var destination= context.Destinations.First();

Mapper.Map<Source, Target>(source, destination)
```

Throws: `AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException`: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

This works:

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>();

var source = new Source();
var destination= new Destination();

Mapper.Map<Source, Target>(source, destination)
```

The entity framework is creating a dynamic proxy class for my `Destination` class is that the reason it doesn't work?

Without destination parameter it works as well i.e.:

```cs
var destination = Mapper.Map<Source, Target>(source);
```

Comment: Ok, so it wasn't so simple. I've created a separate project to test it. And there it works. However I discovered that ef doesn't create dynamic proxies for this project. Could that be the difference? How does ef decide when to use proxy and not? `Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled` is set to true.

Comment: Make sure that all properties of your POCO object are virtual.

Comment: That has nothing to to with it. Yes it needs to be virtual so that the proxy class can override the properties and lazy load navigation properties but I can replicate this exception without using EF. When updating an existing object with automapper the destination type must be exactly the same type as destination object, subclasses is not enough. Se my answer below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is a bug and is fixed on the develop branch of AutoMapper. The prerelease version of AutoMapper has the fix, or wait a little bit for the 2.2.1 release.

Answer (score 0):

So the reason was that ef created a proxy. The exception occurs when subclass is used as destination. It appears that destination type must be the exact same type as the type defined with `CreateMap<>`, derived types doesn't work.

`DynamicMap<>` seems to work though so I will probably use that.